# Rails form_tag not processing :action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, session-variables

I have been working with Rails for a couple of months now, so I am still pretty new to it. I would appreciate any help with the issue I am experiencing.

I have a rails app, running Rails 3.2.14, and Ruby 2.0.0-p353. This rails app also uses twitter-bootstrap-rails (although this is not related to my issue).

The problem: At present the form works correctly. I have been asked to "add" some functionality to the app (I am not the original developer), specifically, to add a language choices (Español or English) as language options. Currently, the selections in the form show up as query string parameters. Based on setting the "language"="Español" or "English" param, I want to set the session[:language].

I am not looking to add Rails Internationalization (I18n), as this implementation will only affect a small, localized part of the app. I am looking to set a session-based cookie variable called ":language" to be used throughout the course of the session. Based on the value of ":language", the app will present the correct language text. When I try to add the :action => "set_language" to the form_tag, nothing happens. It's like it doesn't get processed at all.

In my view: 
show.html.haml:

```
- elsif @evaluation_template.supports_spanish
      .span5{style: "text-align:center;padding-top:30px"}
        = image_tag 'layout/kn-logo.png'
      .well.span5
        %h2 Setup / Disposición
        %br
        = form_tag deployment_path(@deployment, :anchor => "question/1"), :method => :get do
          %p
            Please select your preferred language:
            %br
            Seleccione su idioma preferido:
            %br
            = select_tag :language, "<option>English</option><option>Español</option>".html_safe
            %p
              Please select the position of the evaluator:
              %br
              Por favor seleccione la posición del evaluador:
              %br
                = select_tag 'job_type', @evaluation_template.all_job_types.collect {|job_type_name| "<option value='#{job_type_name}'>#{job_type_name}"}.join('').html_safe
              %p
                Select team members to be excluded from this survey:
                %br
                Seleccionar a los miembros a ser excluidos de esta encuesta:
                %br
                - @deployment.evaluation_instances.each do |instance|
                  = check_box_tag 'exclude[]', instance.team_member.id
                  = instance.team_member.name
                %br
                %br
                  = submit_tag "Begin evaluation / Comenzar la Evaluación", :class => 'begin btn btn-large btn-primary'
```

In my controller, I have added the following code to support setting the session variable:

```
def set_language
  session[:language] = params[:language]
end
```

When submitted, the form is processed by the DeploymentsController#show using the method: => :get

The issue I cannot figure out is, how to add the :action => "set_language" to the form_tag? Or is there a better way to do this. If I have left out any other information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

So I have decided to add a separate form / controller to allow the end user to select their language preference.

Here are some details that are of importance to accomplish this:

The end-user receives URL via e-mail which they click on, which takes them to the evaluations page (so they can complete the evaluation). IF the end-user's evaluation was setup to allow multi-language (Spanish / English) support, then @evaluation_template.supports_spanish = 1 (it's in the model).

What I am looking to accomplish is the following:

Using the controller (DeploymentsController) for the evaluation (deployments#show), I want to redirect the end-user if @evaluation_template.supports_spanish AND if session[:language] (or params[:lang] - whichever is better) has not been set. Also, FYI: params[] is already being used in this app (which why I was thinking about setting params[:lang], and then setting session[:language] based on params[:lang]).

I have added the following to the DeploymentsController, which is redirecting correctly:

```
if @evaluation_template.supports_spanish && params[:lang].nil?
  redirect_to :controller => 'languages', :action => 'show' and return
end
```

AND (in order to determine if params[:lang] has been set, once the user comes back-around after selecting their language).

```
if params.has_key? :lang
  session[:language] = params[:lang]
end
```

I have created a new controller (LanguagesController), that has the following:

```
def show
  options = Hash.new

  @deployment = Deployment.find_by_uuid(params[:id]) || Deployment.find(params[:id])
  @evaluation_template = @deployment.evaluation_instances.first.evaluation_template

  session[:language] = params[:lang]

end
```

My route to facilitate this:

```
resources :languages
get '/languages', to: 'languages#show', as: :set_language
```

and my new form (view) show.html.haml:

```
- if params[:lang].nil?
  #welcome-container
    #row-fluid
      #span12
        .span5{style: "text-align:center;padding-top:30px"}
          = image_tag 'layout/xxxx.png'
        .well.span5
          %h2 Setup / Disposición
          %br
          = form_tag deployment_path(@deployment), :method => :get do
            %p
              %br
              Please select your preferred language:
              %br
              Seleccione su idioma preferido:
              %br
                  = select_tag :lang, "<option>English</option><option>Español</option>".html_safe
            %p
            = submit_tag "Next", :class => 'begin btn btn-large btn-primary'
```

As it stands right now, I am able to redirect to the new form, and I am able to select a language preference. This also sets the params[:lang] correctly, and also sets session[:language] => "Spanish" or "English" correctly when the form is submitted.
The form submits to the DeploymentsController, and the user can continue to select their from the deployments#show view (which I still need to modify for language selection):

```
- if params[:job_type].nil?
#welcome-container
  #row-fluid
    #span12
      .span5{style: "text-align:center;padding-top:30px"}
        = image_tag 'layout/xxxx.png'
      .well.span5
        %h2 Setup
         = form_tag deployment_path(@deployment, :anchor => "question/1"), :method => :get do
          %p
            Please select the position of the evaluator:
            %br
            = select_tag 'job_type', @evaluation_template.all_job_types.collect {|job_type_name| "<option value='#{job_type_name}'>#{job_type_name}"}.join('').html_safe
          %p
            Please select any team members you would like to exclude from this survey:
            %br
            - @deployment.evaluation_instances.each do |instance|
              = check_box_tag 'exclude[]', instance.team_member.id
              = instance.team_member.name
              %br
          = submit_tag "Begin evaluation", :class => 'begin btn btn-large btn-primary'
```

When the user submits this form, they are re-directed to the wrong path (and consequently, the params[:lang] and session[:language] are not set.

```
/languages/88#question/1
```

As opposed to what's in the form_tag:

```
= form_tag deployment_path(@deployment, :anchor => "question/1"), :method => :get do
```

I cannot figure out why this isn't working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any other info, please let me know.

Comment: If i'm not wrong the form is being used to update lot more than the language. If you want to update the language alone, you need a new form first up. I can help you further if you can confirm it.

Comment: You are correct. The form currently sets the following: The position of the evaluator, and to exclude any team members to be excluded from the evaluation. What I am wanting to do is to also add the language selection to the same form.

Comment: Also - at present the form is processed using the GET method via deployments#show. This is the crux of my issue: Can I add an : action to the form to allow me to also set the session variable ?

Comment: If you add an action to the form, the entire form will be submitted to that action only. What you can do is to set the session variable in your current action itself. If that is not allowed, you need a new form

Comment: Okay, so what I need to try and do is, try to set the session variable in the show method, correct?

Comment: Yes. That's what you have to do

Comment: As @arun15thmay said u can either set session in your current action(DeploymentsController#show) or create a completely new action. If none of that suits you then instead of actually submitting the form you can call a javascript function on submit. That javascript function would first set the session and then submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form_tag method takes first parameter as url. So in your case the url(action) = deployment_path

```
form_tag(deployment_path(@deployment, :anchor => "question/1"), :method => :get)
```

And deployment_path would be defined as 'deployment' in routes.rb

If you want to change action of this form then change it to something like

```
form_tag(set_language_path, :method => :get)
```

But make sure your routes has set_language defined.
Something like:

```
get "/language" => "language#show", :as => :set_language
```

Comment: I believe this is what I may end up having to do if I am unable to include setting the language in the same form. If it is not possible to do this, I will probably have to add a view / controller action to allow the user to submit their language, process the request, and land on the view noted above.

Comment: Can you make any suggestions based on the new information I have provided?